# Why is maven throwing an error in exec-maven-plugin for a specific dump

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, exec-maven-plugin

I am using the exec-maven-plugin and facing a very weird problem.

I have the following code

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>import database </id>
                <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>imp</executable>
                    <commandlineArgs>user/user FULL=Y FILE=db_baseline.dmp</commandlineArgs>
                    <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

When I run this, it runs to completion and shows me that the database is importing (even logging to database, I can see all the data) but the plugin is failing with the following error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (import database) on
>   project xxxxx: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an
>   error: 3 (Exit value: 3) -> [Help 1]

What's even more weird, if I use a different dump file then I don't see the error.  Why is that? What could be different or wrong about this dump file that maven is throwing errors?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the same error if you run the program on the command line without Maven? `Exit value: 3` means the script used is returning a code of '3' to Maven, specifically the exec plugin. By default, the `exec:exec` goal expects the "return of 0 means success, non-zero means failed" conventions typically honored by scripts in a Unix world.

If the `imp` executable doesn't honor this convention, use the `<successCodes>` [configuration parameter](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#successCodes) to list which codes indicate success for this executable. The plugin will check the list to decide if it should fail the build.

As to why this file returns the code 3 but others don't - Maven is just passing on the value `imp` returns. You'd have to examine the file contents and the way the script runs to determine what the differences are. I doubt it's anything to do with Maven specifically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. this is exactly the weird thing. Both files runs good and with the same output using the command line.